# Changing a value in a copy of an array changes the value in the original arra

Tags: php, arrays, variables, reference

I have some issues with variables in php that i don't understand.

This is a simplified code example of the issue.

```
//Create an initial array with an sub-array
$a = array();
$a['test'] = array(1,2);

//Create an reference to $a['test'] in $b
//Changing $b[0] should now change the value in $a['test'][0]
$b = &$a['test'];
$b[0] = 3;

//Create an copy of $a into $c
$c = $a;

//Change one value in $c, which is an copy of $a.
//This should NOT change the original value of $a as it is a copy.
$c['test'][1] = 5;

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
print_r($c);
```

This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
)
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
        )

)
```

The script creates an array with an sub-array and puts two values in it.

A reference to the sub-array is then put into b and one of the values in a is changed in this way.

I then make a copy of a into c.

I then change one value of c.

As c is a copy of a i would expect that the change on c did not affect a. But the output tells a different tale.

Can anyone explain why changing a value in the variable $c affect the value in $a when $c is just a copy of $a? Why is there a 5 in the values of $a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found the answer to my own question... On this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

I can't really understand why it does what it does. I do understand that i should probably avoid mixing references and arrays in the future.

Im refering to this section:

> Note, however, that references inside arrays are potentially
>   dangerous. Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a
>   reference on the right side does not turn the left side into a
>   reference, but references inside arrays are preserved in these normal
>   assignments. This also applies to function calls where the array is
>   passed by value. Example:

```
<?php
/* Assignment of scalar variables */
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
$c = $b;
$c = 7; //$c is not a reference; no change to $a or $b

/* Assignment of array variables */
$arr = array(1);
$a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
$arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
$arr2[0]++;
/* $a == 2, $arr == array(2) */
/* The contents of $arr are changed even though it's not a reference! */
?>
```

> In other words, the reference behavior of arrays is defined in an
>   element-by-element basis; the reference behavior of individual
>   elements is dissociated from the reference status of the array
>   container.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning `$b` to `$a` by reference (that's what the `&` prefix does). Any changes to `$b` will effectively modify `$a`. Just force a declaration assignment:

```
$b = $a['test'];
```

`$c` does not modify `$a`. Here's the order of what's going on, and why the arrays are identical:

`$a['test']` is assigned an array of `1,2`.
`$b` is assigned as a reference to `$a['test']`, and modifies its values
`$c` is then assigned to `$a`, which has now been modified by `$b`.

Comment: I want the change on $b to affect the contents of $a. Your code exampled creates and copy of $a['test']

Comment: That's not what you asked though, is it? You asked `Can anyone explain to me what is going on?`, which is what this answer does...

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear in the question. I have edited it. It will hopefully explain it better. I want to know why $c['test'][1] = 3; changes the value in $a.

Comment: No. Your answer only explains up until $c is assigned to $a. My question is about the line after that: $c['test'][1] = 5 . Why does that change $a?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the reference $a to $b by using  `$b = &$a['test'];` Hence

change

```
$b = &$a['test'];
```

to

```
$b = $a['test'];
```

Comment: `&` does not 'copy', it passes by reference. They're significantly different things.

Comment: As BenM says, its completely different things. I wan't it as an reference because i want the change to $b to affect the contents of $a.